# running adb via wifi on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, android, eclipse

First, im new on linux so please bear with me.

I have a rooted android phone and i was able to run the adb via wifi network on windows, where i just need to go to the adb's directory and type `adb connect`.

However, i can't just do that in my ubuntu. Everytime i enter `adb connect`, the terminal always said that i dont have the adb and i must install it. When i check the ADT Bundle (I downloaded the bundled one from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download)), i can see the adb is there inside the platform-tools folder.

I already tried to change the directory to the platform-tools and run the `adb connect` from there, but its still not working.

Do i need to install the adb again via terminal? Or did i miss something?

You may be wondering why dont i just download the adb (again) via terminal and do trial and error? The answer is because i dont have a good internet connection, so i want to avoid unnecessary downloads.

Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is easy enough, i just need to use `./adb connect` instead of `adb connect` on ubuntu. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

First enable `ADB over network` on your android device by running `Developer Options->ADB over network`.

On Ubuntu terminal, goto the folder where sdk platform tools are installed, for example (change `<user>` for your username):

```
cd /home/<user>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

then run:

```
./adb connect <host>:<port>
```

you will verify HOST and PORT on your android phone, when you enable `adb over network`.  For example:

```
./adb connect 192.168.0.107:5555
```

then you must open Android Device Monitor (in Android Studio `Tools->Android->Android Device Manager`

once inside ADM, click on the down arrow under Devices and choose option `Reset adb`.

In terminal, run `adb connect` again.  For example:

```
 ./adb connect 192.168.0.107:5555
```

This will renew your device list and should find your device.